# VideoView prevent initial black screen by seekTo-Method for streamed videos

Tags: android, android-layout, android-mediaplayer, android-view, android-videoview

How do I prevent the initial black screen of a `VideoView`? I don't want to use a placeholder, as I therefore would have to create a previewimage for every VideoView (and I'm using several VideoViews...)

A common solution for this is to use `videoView.seekto(100)` once the video is prepared. But this doesn't work for me. It does set the seeker to the correct position, but the VideoView remains black until the user presses the play-button.

This is my code:

```
mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

@Override
public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

    mVideoView.start();
    mVideoView.seekTo(100);
    mp.setOnSeekCompleteListener(new OnSeekCompleteListener() {

        @Override
        public void onSeekComplete(MediaPlayer mp) {
            mVideoView.pause();

        }
    });
}
```

I also tried this without the `onSeekCompleteListener` and without seperatly starting and pausing the video, but it didn't work either..

anyone a hint for solving this issue?

**EDIT**
I figured out that this is only an issue for **streaming** videos! It's working like a charm for locally stored ones...

and it actually seems to be an official issue... 
https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=4124

Comment: Shouldn't the `seekTo()` come before the `start()`?

Comment: well, therefore I could also just leave start() and pause() out. And this doesn't work for me...

Comment: You ever find a solution to this, I seem to have the same issue.

Comment: @Leo u got solution ? i also facing same

Comment: wouldn't mind if someone of you'd start a bounty on this question ;)